# like's not appearing on facebook, button is working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

so the button works and remembers the likes.
I say it works because looking at the ajax requests there is not error, it's all succesful.

but the like with the link or image is never shown on facebook, I've checked my wall/timeline... nothing...

```
<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Flavidaloca.webelite.be%2Fcontent%2Fdream-productions&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; height:22px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

that's the code I use... it's supposed to work... anybody know why it could fail?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean?  Did you post after the like?  Or just do a like?

I just did a pure like of a techcrunch article and didn't see it appear on my wall or timeline.  Where does it say in Facebook documentation that you are to see it on the wall/timeline?

Comment: I thought that's how it worked ... "john doe likes herp derp"... am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see it happening. Where's the docs that says it does supposed to work like that?

Comment: oh turns out it's not supposed to do that! I'm confusing it with the share button... sorry! and thank you!

Comment: ok, whew!  You had me concerned that there was something more that should have been happening.